# Gradle tarda mucho minificando apk

Tags: android, gradle

Llevo esperando más de 20 minutos para que gradle compile en release minificando y ofuscando el código con proguard:

```
release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    shrinkResources true
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

<============-> 93% EXECUTING [22m 37s]
```

Es normal? Cuanto suele durar este proceso?

Comment: A mí no me suele tardar más de 2 o 3 minutos. ¿Es muy grande tu aplicación? ¿Tiene muchas librerías contenidas?

Comment: No, no tiene muchas la verdad

Comment: Lo he cancelado y vuelta a empezar, esta vez me dio errores antes del 93% y pude corregirlos